# Why is exponential time 2^n^k and not 2^n

Tags: time-complexity

Does 2^n describe a class of problems or is it considered polynomial?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What makes you think $2^n$ is not considered exponential time?

Comment: This, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time
defines EXPTIME as 2^n^k for a constant k, where I would expect 2^k

Comment: For a constant $k$, $2^k$ is constant.